# Android Cordova App not Installed issue

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, java-7, java-6

we currently have an app that has been in usage for several years now. We are currently facing an issue with deployment where users are failing to install updates to the existing app.

this is the error they see when trying to install on an android device:

[image: Android App not installed]

As far as I can tell the app is being correctly signed with the proper certificate. I even checked the previous release apk with the new release/update apk. both the certificate seem to match perfectly.

[image: Java KeyTool check between the two apk's]

the only thing I can recall being changed is I have switched to a newer PC, my old PC is gone and now I am working with visual studio 2017 instead of the previous visual studio 2015 to build the release apk files from cordova still using the same keystore file to sign the release apk. would switching computers impact the signing of the apk even though the keystore file is still the same?